# ES6 iterate contain const

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why i get error in this code?btw im still new in es6, thanks

```
selData.map((item,idx)=>({ 

        const TargetItem = aclEntries.findIndex(rec=>rec.stakeholder_id===item.value)          

        console.log(TargetItem)  



        }))
```

Comment: Remove the `(` in front of the function block, else it'll be parsed as an object (which will fail) (same thing for after the end of the block)

Comment: It should also be noted that you are using .map, and currently returning `undefined` (no explicit return) for each item, which would result in a new Array entirely filled with `undefined`. So, whatever you’re trying to do, if you’re not planning to return a new Array, maybe forEach would be a better choice. Otherwise, don’t forget to return the thing(s) you want from each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 functions can be written a few different ways.

```
// If you have more than 1 param, you have to wrap them with `()`
const functionName = (param1, param2) => { return console.log(param1, param2); }

// If you're just returning a value, you can omit the `{}`
const functionName = (param1, param2) => console.log(param1, param2);

// If you only have 1 param, you can omit the `()` around the params
const functionName = param1 => console.log(param);
```

I added another example into the code below, `.find()`, which will give you the results of `aclEntries`, not just the index position.

Also, I'm using `forEach` instead of `map`, as `map` creates a new array, and you're not assigning the return value of `map` to a variable for later use.

```js
const aclEntries = [
  { stakeholder_id: '1234', taco: 'cat' }
];
const selData = [
  { value: '1234' }
];

selData.forEach((item) => {
  const TargetItemIndex = aclEntries.findIndex(rec => rec.stakeholder_id === item.value);
  const TargetItemContent = aclEntries.find(rec => rec.stakeholder_id === item.value);
  
  console.log('index', TargetItemIndex);
  console.log('content', TargetItemContent);
})
```